# The system version of Tk is deprecated

Tags: macos, terminal, catalina, homebrew, python

I installed python3 and tcl-tk with homebrew on my iMac. However, when I want to launch my program using the terminal, this message is displayed:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The system version of Tk is deprecated and may be removed in a future release. Please don't rely on it. Set TK_SILENCE_DEPRECATION=1 to suppress this warning.

The interface is completely buggy on my iMac and I don't understand why and can't find a solution.

On my MacBook Air with the same homebrew apps installed the very same program works perfectly.

Details:

- macOS Catalina 10.15.4 on both Macs
- MacBook Air:

  ```
  @MacBook-Air $ which python3
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
  @MacBook-Air $ python3 -V
  Python 3.7.3
  @MacBook-Air $ which tclsh
  /usr/bin/tclsh
  ```
- iMac:

  ```
  @iMac-de-Lola.local $ which python3
  /usr/local/bin/python3
  @iMac-de-Lola.local $ python3 -V
  Python 3.7.7
  @iMac-de-Lola.local $ which tclsh
  /usr/bin/tclsh
  ```

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve the problem by installing python 3.7.7 from python.org. The path is now the same as on my MacBook Air.

The program is working very well now. I think the python3 command launches a system version of python and not the version installed by homebrew.